# Google maps auto complete and ajax calls

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, firebug

While using [google maps](http://maps.google.com/), I noticed that it doesn't show any ajax calls from my firebug plug-in. If not doing ajax, how Google Maps auto complete retieve these results? And if it is done via Ajax, how can I make these calls show u on my firebug ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The request being sent is not an AJAX call but a [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) request. It will probably be visible in firebug's Net panel, although not as an AJAX request.

**Request**

> {"pageref":"http://maps.google.com/","startedDateTime":"2011-12-20T12:37:36.906Z","time":44,"request":{"method":"GET","url":"https://maps.google.com/maps/suggest?q=tes&cp=3&hl=en&gl=&v=2&clid=1&json=a&ll=37.09024,-95.712891&spn=41.682395,135.263672&vpsrc=1&authuser=0&auth=4ef0811d3hFK2Vt9KuA9KgqX241QxxsMOjY&src=1,2&num=5&numps=3&callback=*xdc*._9gwewfhfr","httpVersion":"HTTP/1.1","headers":[],"queryString":[{"name":"q","value":"tes"},{"name":"cp","value":"3"},{"name":"hl","value":"en"},{"name":"gl","value":""},{"name":"v","value":"2"},{"name":"clid","value":"1"},{"name":"json","value":"a"},{"name":"ll","value":"37.09024,-95.712891"},{"name":"spn","value":"41.682395,135.263672"},{"name":"vpsrc","value":"1"},{"name":"authuser","value":"0"},{"name":"auth","value":"4ef0811d3hFK2Vt9KuA9KgqX241QxxsMOjY"},{"name":"src","value":"1,2"},{"name":"num","value":"5"},{"name":"numps","value":"3"},{"name":"callback","value":"*xdc*._9gwewfhfr"}],"cookies":[],"headersSize":246,"bodySize":0},"response":{"status":200,"statusText":"OK","httpVersion":"HTTP/1.1","headers":[{"name":"date","value":"Tue, 20 Dec 2011 12:36:02 GMT"},{"name":"content-encoding","value":"gzip"},{"name":"x-content-type-options","value":"nosniff"},{"name":"status","value":"200 OK"},{"name":"content-length","value":"687"},{"name":"x-xss-protection","value":"1; mode=block"},{"name":"server","value":"mustang-server"},{"name":"x-frame-options","value":"SAMEORIGIN"},{"name":"content-type","value":"application/javascript; charset=utf-8"},{"name":"cache-control","value":"private, max-age=600"},{"name":"version","value":"HTTP/1.1"},{"name":"expires","value":"Tue, 20 Dec 2011 12:36:02 GMT"}],"cookies":[],"content":{"size":1712,"compression":2085,"mimeType":"application/javascript"},"redirectURL":"","headersSize":373,"bodySize":-373},"cache":{},"timings":{"blocked":0,"dns":-1,"connect":-1,"send":1,"wait":39,"receive":3,"ssl":-1}}

**Response**

> *xdc*._9gwewfhfr&&*xdc*._9gwewfhfr([,,,[["Tesoro Drive, San Antonio, TX, United States",[[[0,12,,"0x865cf5335491854f:0x804f460e644d0f1a",1,,,,1,0,3,,,,17],[14,25,,"0x865c58af04d00eaf:0x856e13b10a016bc",,,,,,,,,,,37],[27,29,,"0x864070360b823249:0x16eb1c8f1808de3c",,,,,,,,,,,545],[31,44,,"0x54eab584e432360b:0x1c3bb99243deb742",,,,,,,,,,,33]]],2,,,,,,,,,,,,,,17,,,,0.020595163829848169],["Tesuque, NM, United States",[[[0,7,,"0x87184f03a765808b:0x8aeee8e60541223e",1,,,,1,0,3,,,,37],[9,11,,"0x87185043e79852a9:0x46bf6e1a63359eba",,,,,,,,,,,545],[13,26,,"0x54eab584e432360b:0x1c3bb99243deb742",,,,,,,,,,,33]]],2,,,,,,,,,,,,,,37,,,,0.019492331490231142],["Tesla, Irvine, CA, United States",[[[0,5,,"0x80dce7df590dbc15:0x52e30532cd794543",1,,,,1,0,3,,,,17],[7,13,,"0x80dcdd0e689140e3:0xa77ab575604a9a39",,,,,,,,,,,37],[15,17,,"0x808fb9fe5f285e3d:0x8b5109a227086f55",,,,,,,,,,,545],[19,32,,"0x54eab584e432360b:0x1c3bb99243deb742",,,,,,,,,,,33]]],2,,,,,,,,,,,,,,17,,,,0.017660511607338017],["Tesla Motors, Bing Street, San Carlos, CA, United States",[[[0,12,,"0x808fa23f24ceeee3:0xefa80b30085cc838",1,,,,1,0,3,,,,53522],[14,25,,"0x808fa23f4145ca13:0xfaa07d7eca8579ce",,,,,,,,,,,17],[27,37,,"0x808fa1f400fc6877:0xfa780f9d24186988",,,,,,,,,,,37],[39,41,,"0x808fb9fe5f285e3d:0x8b5109a227086f55",,,,,,,,,,,545],[43,56,,"0x54eab584e432360b:0x1c3bb99243deb742",,,,,,,,,,,33]]],2,,,,,,,,,,,,,,53522,,,,0.01464858003576174],["Tescott, KS, United States",[[[0,7,,"0x87a32978a850e051:0xe732fd69b6b2dede",1,,,,1,0,3,,,,37],[9,11,,"0x87a31771717c016b:0x68c2b4a94b3e095f",,,,,,,,,,,545],[13,26,,"0x54eab584e432360b:0x1c3bb99243deb742",,,,,,,,,,,33]]],2,,,,,,,,,,,,,,37,,,,0.014647293410062903]],,,30,,1,,[6.0856041798706649e-08]]);